# What is a "hand‑tooled mitre‑crozier applique"?

Tags: word-usage, phrases

In Dan Brown's novel *The Da Vinci Code*, a bishop, in an attempt not to stand out in the airport crowd or on the plane, wears a certain type of outfit. It's been quoted multiple times by critics, including the most reputable ones, and it leaves some readers to wonder whether the author is mocking them. Be that as it may, here it is:

> Only those with a keen eye would notice his 14‑karat gold bishop’s
> ring with purple amethyst, large diamonds, and hand‑tooled
> mitre‑crozier applique.

Okay, so we have a ring adorned with amethyst and large diamonds.

A mitre is a type of headgear. A crozier is a bishop's staff. An applique is an "ornamentation, as a cutout design, that is sewn on to or otherwise applied to a piece of material."

Is the hand-tooled mitre-crozier applique part of that ring? Or is it a separate item?

If so, what kind of item?

Comment: Something like this maybe http://archives-archtoronto.blogspot.com/2017/08/record-of-week-archbishop-walshs.html

Comment: If you google "appliqued ring" or similar you'll find plenty of examples of rings with applique. This would probably be better asked on the Literature board or maybe even one of the religion boards or the crafting board, because you know what the words mean and the grammar, you just don't know what a bishop is likely to wear; knowledge of English grammar won't help you understand the sentence any further.

Comment: @StuartF asking for the meaning of words is neither off-topic. I've seen hundreds of, if not more, weird, archaic, quasi-neologistic words being asked on EL&U.

Comment: Ricky, is a 'hand-tooled' (anything) by itself not obvious? Is a 'mitre‑crozier' by itself not obvious? Is the 'applique' process by itself not obvious? Then please, what remains?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Since it's all so obvious, what would the final product look like?

Comment: Ho ho ho and do you know no bishops who might show you theirs? The final product would be a hat with some embroidery applied by hand, which why not search in your engine of choice?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Very good, Santa. Problem is I've searched and searched. The best my search engine could come up with was an intricately designed ring, not a hat. What say you?

Comment: What say I, Ricky, is GIGO: garbage in, garbage out. 

Try as you might to ignore it, the final product would be a hat with some embroidery applied by hand.

That the right question wasn't posed says of any answer only that it was based on the wrong question. Oops!

Why might anyone might Post a Question here without first researching it - preferably exhaustively - which you did not. Can you justify that?

In your view, what do those who prefer arguing to accepting simple logic, say about themselves?

Again, why not ask your search engine of choice?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: I have, in fact, done quite a bit of research, and any sensible answer would satisfy me even now. "Garbage in, garbage out"- fine, do please suggest what keywords I'm supposed to use, and, while you at it, you might want to tell me why you're so firmly convinced that the item in question is a hat?

Comment: The clues are in the exposition, but Brown was writing a mystery, however badly. Appliqué normally applies to embroidery but by extension broad enough for Brown to jump on, covers intricate forms of design such as engraving on ceramics or gemstones. So the ring does have a hand-carved image, prolly of a bishop’s hat, prolly placed in front of or atop his staff of office.

Comment: An applique in jewelry can be a stone (gemstone or fake) that is set into a surface. It's possible the crozier and mitre are set into or glued into the amethyst, and that they were made by hand.

Answer (score 2):

I would understand it to mean a logo of the bishop's mitre and crozier something like [this](https://www.everypixel.com/image-10685754984642576534) engraved on the ring. However, *hand-tooled* usually refers to engraving on leather, not gold, and, as you say, *appliqué* usually refers to applied decoration on fabric.

Comment: Aye, there's the rub. Ring designs are hand-tooled more or less by definition, especially where the ring in question is expensive and therefore not mass-produced. But "appliqué"?! I would write it off as an example of the author's much-celebrated inferior writing style and leave it at that if it weren't for the critics (in The Telegraph and other venues) sounding like they understood what the author meant.

Comment: Further on: "Trying to ease his nerves, the bishop meditated on the purple amethyst in his ring. Feeling the textures of the mitre-crozier appliqué and the facets of the diamonds, he reminded himself that this ring was a symbol of power far less than that which he would soon attain."

Comment: Oh, Kate… while you're right in what you said,  did you have to give Ricky so much licence? Look what he's done with it!

Comment: @Ricky: isn't it clear what the phrase means, even if Dan Brown is using an inappropriate term here?

Comment: @PeterShor: First of all, no, not altogether clear. Second of all, which term is inappropriate? "mitre‑crozier" or "applique"?  Please clarify.

Comment: Grammatically, the “hand-tooled mitre-crozier” has to be part of the ring. Appliqués don’t go on rings, so it’s clearly an inappropriate term.  Thus, it’s a ring decorated (somehow) with a mitre and crozier. Do you really need a more specific description?

Comment: @PeterShor: No, yours is quite sufficient, in fact. Thank you.

Comment: Complaining about Dan Brown's English is a professional sport: [Here's Geoff Pullum's classic essay where he dissects the very first sentence like a worm.](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/000844.html)